# What is the difference between git clone --mirror and pull

Tags: git, git-clone, git-pull

There really is no difference between clone and pull is my understanding. Or in other words `git clone -- bare` and `git pull` does the same. But since `git clone --mirror` updates the local references would it be different from pull ?

---

EDIT: I mistakenly assumed git clone default is --bare. But --bare will be setup without working directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git clone` creates a new repository.  You had no repository before, and now you have one.

`git pull` does operations in an existing repository.

That seems like a really big difference!

Other than that, what `git pull` does is:

- run `git fetch`, then
- run a second Git command.

Since a `--mirror` clone is a `--bare` clone and therefore has no work-tree, the second command that `git pull` would run will fail, no matter whether you choose merge or rebase.

What `git fetch` does is [documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch.html).  With a mirror clone, the default refspec is `+refs/*:refs/*`, so that all references are replaced with those obtained from the other Git.